# Google Pie Chart : How can I change the color of lines in the legend?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization, pie-chart

i have a pie chart where the legend's position is set to 'labeled', so the slice description and values are placed on a line next to the pie. What i want to do now is to change the color of the lines which connect the slices with the matching legend, to the color of the corresponding slice.

Is there any attribute in legend.textStyle or somewhere else which allows this change?

Here's my Code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {
        width: '800',
        height: '400',
        title: "So, how was your day?",
        legend: {
          position: 'labeled',
          textStyle: {
            color: 'gray'    // sets the text color
          }
        }
      });
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Greetings, 
Andi

Comment: There is no option in the API to control the color of the lines connecting the legend to the pie slices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, asgallant. Maybe there will be a feature in the future which provides this functionality.

Comment: You can make a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support.

Answer (score 6):

Google charts are rendered by using `svg` technology, so it is possible to style them. Though you will have to use some hard-coded indexes for the elements.

[image: Google pie chart with colored lines]

I have implemented a function `replaceLabelColors` that gets the corresponding `g` tags and replace their attributes.

For your example it can be used so:

```
var dataLength = data.J.length; // 5
var colors = ["#3366cc","#dc3912","#ff9900","#109618","#990099","#0099c6","#dd4477","#66aa00","#b82e2e","#316395",
          "#994499","#22aa99","#aaaa11","#6633cc","#e67300","#8b0707","#651067","#329262","#5574a6","#3b3eac","#b77322",
          "#16d620","#b91383","#f4359e","#9c5935","#a9c413","#2a778d","#668d1c","#bea413","#0c5922","#743411"];

var chartId = "visualization"
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(chartId));
chart.draw(data, { width: '800', height: '400', title: "So, how was your day?", colors: colors, legend: { position: 'labeled', textStyle: { color: 'gray' }}});

var graphics = document.getElementById(chartId).querySelectorAll("svg > g");
// graphics[0] is title, graphics[1..n] are pie slices, and we take label area which is graphics[n+1]
var labelsGraphics = graphics[dataLength+1].childNodes; 

// get svg graphics and replace colors
var replaceLabelColors = function(){
    var colorIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < labelsGraphics.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            // skip even indexes
            continue;
        } else {
            var currentLine = labelsGraphics[i];
            currentLine.childNodes[0].setAttribute("stroke", colors[colorIndex]); // <path stroke="#636363" ...>
            currentLine.childNodes[1].setAttribute("fill", colors[colorIndex]); // <circle fill="#636363" ...>
            colorIndex++;
        }
    }
}

replaceLabelColors();
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "onmouseover", replaceLabelColors);
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "onmouseout", replaceLabelColors);
```

Comment: How do you fix that white on white text? The `.8%` in `45.8%` is obscured.

Comment: @DavidYell probably by using `pieSliceTextStyle: { color: 'gray' } `, you can find chart properties here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Comment: If you want to reverse the text & percentage/number, it's possible. If the text like "Sleep", "Watch TV" runs to 2 or more lines, then we need to do more work, using siblings of the g with percentage/number & text, and g with the line.